# Save Data always in the first Cell UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I have a UICollectionView and i want to save the data (images) always in the first cell and the old data walks to the next cells. So when i save a new photo it´s comes in the first cell, i have tried with indexpath.row == 0 {} in cellForRowAtIndexPath but he saves only in the first cell in the other cells are nothing. Can i invert the save index or give it a another way ??

So have anyone a idea what i can make there ??

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return picture.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BookPicCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookPicCell

    let cellcore = picture[indexPath.row]



    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         cell.BookImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: cellcore.foto!)

    }



    return cell
}
```

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of UIImages and append the new image to the front of that array:

```
pictures.insert(newImage, atIndex : 0)
```

Than after you inserted your new image you need to reload your UICollectionView using:

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

You do not want to sort your data inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: I use core data and save the image as String so i have this code ` let newpic=NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("EveryPicture", inManagedObjectContext: self.mgdContext) as! EveryPicture newpic.everyfoto?.insert(bildPfad, atIndex: 0)` with insert comes an Error that can not convert String to typ Character. I have never hear from Character can i convert that ?

Comment: If you know they are of type string you can check if your cast fails by being more precise to the compiler. use: 
let picturesArray : [String] = ... as! [String]. This way you know if you have an array of String or something else.